# create-react-app/express Proxy error: Could not proxy request (ECONNRESET)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, fetch-api

I have created a react app using create-react-app and an express server using express-generator.  My react app is running on http://localhost:3000 and my express server is running on http://localhost:8080. In my component I am making a POST fetch request to my express server, which is successfully running my express router code, returning a 200 response status code. However, the client console logs the following error and does not receive the response:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /components/findAlbumArt from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

In the browser under the network tab I can see that the `findAlbumArt` request now has the status `(canceled)`.

My react code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    let response = await fetch("/components/findAlbumArt", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        value: this.state.value,
      }),
    });

    response = await response.json();

    this.props.setAlbumArt(response.albumArtUrl);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Find an album that you love:{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>{" "}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

My express code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cache = require("../bin/cache/cache");
const axios = require("axios");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/findAlbumArt", async (req, res, next) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({
      albumArtUrl:
        "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2739feadc48ab0661e9b3a9170b",
    });

    // I commented out my other code to simply test returning a success response
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Other relevant files:

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const createError = require("http-errors");
const logger = require("morgan");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

let app = express();

const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const componentsRouter = require("./routes/components");

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/components", componentsRouter);
app.use("/", indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

express package.json

```
{
  "name": "onboarding",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async-redis": "^1.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  }
}
```

client package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved the problem myself actually. I was missing `event.preventDefault();` in the `handleSubmit()` handler function.

The browser page was reloading when the submit button was clicked, causing the request to be canceled before completing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. This solved half the problems I was having with a nearly identical issue. The other half is that I was accidentally using `response.send()` in my Axios responses. So basically I was trying to use express responses on the front end which was pretty dumb. Guess I spaced on it while I was writing it.

Comment: Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the window is being refreshed. Maybe forgot to prevent default behavior.

I was getting the same error when I was (purposely) refreshing a page for testing purposes. I removed the

window.location.reload(); command

and the proxy error disappeared.

just re-render the react component instead.